# Create new branch from a repository which was forked before

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I have forked a public repository A into B. 
A has a branch called "dev" which is also in B, where I committed to.
Now unrelated changes to A need to be done so that I am able to make a PR from B.

How can I get a new "dev" branch into B so that I can commit the needed changes before I send the PR from B ?

To simplify, the scheme is like this:

A

- dev

B

- dev (needs to wait for changes in new dev to be merged into A dev)
- newdev (will merge to A dev before B dev can be merged)

Answer (score 1):

When you fork B, and then clone B and work with it locally, you essentially have 3 separate repositories: A, B and your local C.

In your local repository C you can add A and B as "remotes". Check `git remote -v` to see which remotes you have. I would give them descriptive names at this point. You can [rename a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-remote/) and [add a new remote](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/) to your local repo, let's say: A = origin, B = fork.

If you add these remotes and run `git fetch` you'll get 3 distinct branches: `dev` (your local dev), `origin/dev` ("dev" on A), and `fork/dev` ("dev" on B).

Now, at this point to avoid confusion I would give your local branches `dev` and `newdev` more descriptive names that reflect the work you are doing, and use these names instead. For example if `dev` has feature *foo* implemented, and `newdev` is going to have feature *bar* implemented, you can do:

```
# make "foo" branch to refer locally to the "dev" state on B
git branch foo fork/dev 
# make "bar" branch to refer locally to the "dev" state on A
git branch bar origin/dev
```

Now you can `git checkout bar`, implement your feature, push it to fork (aka B) with `git push fork`, go to github and make your PR. The interface will let you choose your source branch (`bar`) and your destination branch (`origin/dev`).